# Is this Mealy representation correct for 011?

Tags: digital-logic, sequential-logic

I am practicing on moore and mealy machine sequence detectors and I want to make sure if the mealy 011 sequence detector is correct.
[image]

Comment: No, it's not. You have two transitions from the first state labeled the same.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, for the first transition it should be 0/0 and for the last state when I get 1 it should go to the initial state. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mealy and Moore State Diagrams to detect serial bit sequence 011.

[image: Mealy & Moore State Diagrams]